# Intermittent login loop with Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 a few weeks back. Sometimes when I log in, I'll end up right back at the login screen. After two or three log in attempts, I finally get through to the desktop.

Tonight, it's gotten worse. no matter how many times I log in, I end up back at the login screen. TTY logins (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) work successfully. I can also access the account in GUI mode using Chrome Remote Desktop.

I created another account and it does successfully log in to that account, but I'd like to repair the original account so that I don't lose all the configuration work I've done over time.

Installing `lxde-desktop` and logging in with that (*not* `lxde-qt`) allows me to log in normally.

What I've tried:

- checked ownership of `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority`, which were owned by the correct user instead of `root`
- purged and reinstalled `lightdm`

Model names:

```
Computer:  Lenovo Ideapad 520S-14IKB
RAM:       Crucial Technology BLS16G4S26BFSD.16FBD 16GB DDR4-2666 SODIMM 1.2V
CPU:       Intel Core i5-8250U @ 1.60GHz
GPU:       Intel UHD Graphics 620
Disk:      Intel SSDSC2KW25
```

Comment: that seems to be a keyboard layout 'joke'

Comment: Are you sure that's the full disk model name?

Comment: sudo lshw -html > ~/hardware_info.html
This is the command I used to get the info.
Can you give me a hint on how to investigate this issue? If I run
>journalctl -b 
I got this:

Comment: <pre>mai 19 23:05:20 len lightdm[911]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No
mai 19 23:05:20 len lightdm[911]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
mai 19 23:05:20 len lightdm[911]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: 
mai 19 23:05:20 len lightdm[911]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
mai 19 23:05:20 len avahi-daemon[752]: Server startup complete. Host name is len.local. Local service cookie is 2541646116.</code>

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit : Chrome-Remote-Desktop. It seems that it manage to mingle with the authentication. On login it requires kwallet. I guess they tested only in kde environment and based the security on kwallet. 
Solution :  apt purge chrome-remote-desktop.

Comment: I had the same issue and the Chrome Remote Desktop purge also worked for me. Thanks so much.

Comment: I should add that I had the same issue in Ubuntu 18.04 and ended up reinstalling.